# Conditional operator error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, expression, conditional-operator

I was writing a basic program to find if the input number is prime or not. I have a `checkPrime(num)` function that checks for prime number and returns `true` if num is prime else returns `false`. Now in my `main()` function I used conditional operator to shorten the code but I am getting an error which I am not sure about.

Below is my code:

```
static void Main(String[] args) {
    int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    while (n-- > 0) {
        int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        (checkPrime(num) == true) ? Console.WriteLine("Prime") : Console.WriteLine("Not Prime");
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get the error as `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement` in my while loop at conditional statement line. I am not sure what is it that I am missing. There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820277/only-assignment-call-increment-decrement-await-and-new-object-expressions-c) and people have answered that the conditional operator line is an expression and not a statement so there has to be some sort or assignment for the value of the expression. Same kind of example is given in [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) where the explanation does something like this

```
// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input > 0) ? "positive" : "negative";
```

But what I am not able to understand is in my function all I am trying to do is check the return value of the function and then print the output. So where does this expression thing comes in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method Call using Ternary Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490095/method-call-using-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) is an *expression*, not a statement, that means it cannot stand alone, as the result has to be used somehow. In your code, you don't use the result, but try to produce *side effects* instead.

Depending on the condition before the `?` the operator *returns the result* of either the first or the second expression. But `Console.WriteLine()`'s return type is `void`. So the operator *has nothing to return*. `void` is not a valid return type for the `?:` operator. So a `void`-method cannot be used here.

So you could do something like that:

```
while (n-- > 0) {
    int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    string result = checkPrime(num) ? "Prime" : "Not Prime";
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

or you use the operator inside the `Console.WriteLine()` call:

```
while (n-- > 0) {
    int num = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(checkPrime(num) ? "Prime" : "Not Prime");
}
```

In both examples, the operator *returns one of the two strings depending on the condition*. That's what this operator is for.

---

*Note* that you do not need to compare the result of `checkPrime()` to `true`. The result already is a `bool`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I get it now. I always thought its one line replacement of if-else but your explanation makes sense. thanks again.