# eval in Anchor tag href only assignment call increment error

Tags: c#, anchor, eval

```
<a href="<%# getsession() == "null" ? "campaigndetails.aspx?id = Eval("id")" : "startcampaign3.aspx?id =  Eval("id")" %> "></a>
```

-

```
public string getsession()
{
    if (Session["user"] == null)
    {
        return "null";
    }
    else
        return Convert.ToString(Session["user"]);
}
```

May I know what is wrong with my code?

Error is:

> Only Assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expression can be used as statement.

Comment: Accepted answer for this question gives some info about this. But, not entirely sure if it clarifies everything in this context. See if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572777/c-sharp-conditional-operator-error-only-assignment-call-increment-decrement

Comment: Also, can you try using <%= %> instead of <%# %>.